# Karpenter consolidation without any downtime for pods

Tags: amazon-eks, autoscaling, high-availability, karpenter

I have karpenter deployed in eks and for karpenter provisioner I have consolidation enabled true

```
  consolidation:
    enabled: true
```

which means for any underutilized node, the workload (pods) will be deployed in the existing nodes. but during this process I have noticed karpenter terminates the existing pod and then creates a new pod.

I am looking for a soluction where the new pod will the created in the existing node first and then terminate the pod in the underutilized node then terminate the node.

Answer (score 1):

Karpenter consolidation works by cordoning a node and draining the pods from the node before deleting it. This causes the pods to be evicted and re-created by their controllers in order to be rescheduled. So, a downtime can get introduced.

The available possibilities are:

- If there is only 1 replica of the pod, then `Pod Disruption Budget` and annotation `karpenter.sh/do-not-evict: true` are the ways to stop the node from being terminated.
- Have multiple replicas of the pod and use node `affinity`, `anti-affinity` to have pod replicas placed in separate nodes to have minimum disruption during consolidation.

Comment: thank you so much, this helped me a lot while working with jenkins pods for builds that run sporadically on eks, this makes karpenter consolidation much more nicer for long running builds

Answer (score 0):

Configure Pod Disruption Budgets, https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/run-application/configure-pdb/

Comment: The pod disruption budget blocks the node deproviosioning itself.
I don't want that.

If there consolidation enabled in porviosioner that before terminating the pod I just want the same pod to be deployed in available node and then terminate the existing pod.