# Karpenter consolidation downtime

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, amazon-eks, karpenter

Topic:
Karpenter/EKS

Observed behavior:

1. Karpenter scales out nodes with various instance types as work load increases.
2. Karpenter creates a few new nodes (ex. t3.medium instances x3)
3. While pods are initializing (before running) on those new nodes, Karpenter decides that it is better to use a single bigger instance (ex. t3.2xlarge x1) and decides to terminate all the pods both pending and running and starts to schedule the pods on the new node and this causes down time.

Question:
Is there a way to take advantage of Karpenter's flexibility of changing instances types and size freely but also at the same time make sure at least 1 pod is always available?

Attempts:
Tried to set the PodDisruptionBudget to have at least 1 min available and while this does ensure that at least 1 pod is always avaialble, the issue arises when Karpenter finds better options for EC2 instance or when it needs to scale down. For example, if a new t3.2xlarge was created due to load increase and after some time the load decreases, then I end up with one t3.2xlarge instance running a single/a couple pods as it cannot be deleted due to the PDB.

Expected Behavior:
Expected Karpenter to make sure to keep one node and make sure that at least one Pod is available until a new node with new Pods are running before changing instances and terminating all pods.

Comment: PDB should resolve the case, I think you need to test some PDB configuration. Hope this help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76637639/karpenter-consolidation-without-any-downtime-for-pods?rq=2

Comment: Hey thank you for the response! As I have stated, if I do add PDB and ensure that 1 pod is always available, the problem arises when the number of pods decreases to 1 from a larger number of pods like 10.
Because consolidation will create 1 large instance to add the multiple pods, when the number of pods decreases back down to 1, I will end up with a large EC2 instance with 1 single pod as it cannot be consolidated due to the PDB

Please let me know if you need more clarification

Comment: How about choosing a suitable node group when you deploy that deployment?